# Android write new line in file

Tags: android, line

I have a problem. My codes,

```
private static final String Separator = "\r\n";
File logFile = new File(myLogFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true)));
                String str = "Test" + "Test2" + "Msg";          
                out.print(str + Separator);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
```

But this code, not add any newline in file.

Thanks...

Comment: where do you want the new line?

Comment: try   out.println(str);

Comment: Its not working... Not add new line. And my program's config file not showing on cumputer. Why ?

Comment: Do you want new line between Test, Test2 and Msg? Also not sure if this has any catch but your file name is logFile and you have passed myFile in FileWriter.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way:

```
private static final String Separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

**[System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)**

**line.separator** - *Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files*

Comment: If using Java 7, `System.lineSeparator()` can be used in lieu of `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an optimum solution but it works:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"};
out.print(TextUtils.join("\n", str));
```

Output:

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
 PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)));
 pr.println(data);
 pr.close();
```